# Chaining a dynamic number of HTTP calls in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am developing an application and I encountered some difficulties in the following situation.

I have an url that at its end accepts a pageSize and the current page, and what I am trying to do is using that URL, get in a list all the elements from a database table, without knowing how many pages I actually have (could be one page of data or could be 1 million pages).

For example, after I make a request with lets say page size 50 and page 1, I want to receive page 2, and if page 2 has 50 elements in it, to receive page 3, if it has anything less than 50 elements to stop there and return in the end all the data I received until now, and nothing to be returned until I made a last request.

What I tried to do is the following thing:

```
 return this.http.get(url + currentPage, { headers }).pipe(
 mergeMap((response: any) => {
    managedObject = managedObject.concat(response.managedObjects);
    if (response.managedObjects.length === pageSizeNo) {
      currentPage++;
      this.http.get(url + currentPage, { headers });
    } else {
      return managedObject;
    }
  })
);
```

I initially give the url with pageSizeNo = 50 defined in it and currentPage = 1, then after I receive the response I want to go further and make another call or return everything I received until now. The problem is that everything stops at page 2, and no further call happens.

This is how I subscribe to what the function returns:

```
this.service.fetchData()
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.qualityData = response
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expand` operator to recursively call http-get. E.g.:

```js
return this.http.get(url + currentPage, { headers }).pipe(
 expand((response: any) => {
    managedObject = managedObject.concat(response.managedObjects);
    if (managedObject.length === pageSizeNo) {
      currentPage++;
      return this.http.get(url + currentPage, { headers });
    } else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  }),
  // combine all emitted values into one array
  toArray()
)
```

Try this [expand operator example](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/expand/)

NOTE: `currentPage` might leak, so be careful with it.

Comment: Well, it sort of worked, but still not really there. Right now it makes all the calls but it instead of returning all the lets say 500 datas at once, it always returns the result of every call, when it should combine all the 50 datas from every call and return only when no more calls are made.

Comment: @Artyomska, oh yeah, forgot that. Add `.toArray()` at the end. I'll update the example

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work, and I receive the "Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'" error :/

Comment: @Artyomska riiight, import it as an operator and pipe it

Comment: Everything worked now, and the data is received as it should be. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Artyomska, you're welcome! Once again, be careful with the `currentPage` thing. If you subscribe twice to that same stream -- it can be buggy. To fix that you might either [`share`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/share/) output stream or incorporate page number to the stream data itself (as in the linked expand example).

Answer (score 1):

```ts
function getPage(pageNo: number): Observable<{ managedObjects: any[] }> {
  return this.http.get(`url?page=${pageNo}`, { headers });
}

of([0, false, []] as [number, boolean, any[]]).pipe(
  expand(([pageNo, isFinal, allResults]) => getPage(pageNo).pipe(
    map(newResults => [
      pageNo + 1,
      newResults.managedObjects.length < 50,
      [...allResults, ...newResults.managedObjects]
    ] as [number, boolean, any[]])
  )),
  takeWhile(([pageNo, isFinal, allResults]) => !isFinal, true),
  last(),
  map(([pageNo, isFinal, allResults]) => allResults)
).subscribe(finalResults => {
  // ...
});
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tyuefr?file=index.ts for a working example